# using a bot ... request blocker script & vpnapi.io TO BLOCK Google Adsense Fake Clickers

Tags: php, api, adsense

since a while I always used your super strackoverfloW
for any all & lots of my Questions i needed to be anwered, thank you so far.

Now it is time that i Contribute Sth to the Comunity also

I am currently Using the Request Blocker Script by "Szczepan K"
in order to block requests if the hit my site too often in a given time
and today additionally i added vpnapp.io to block vpn & proxy
BECAUSE: I want to find a way to BLOCK / AVOID Fake Clickers
Clicking onto my Google Adsense Ads, because the xxx th time
my Adsense Account has been resticted because Google says
invalid Access detected, there must be some idiots wanna
disreputate me and fake clicking my ads on purpose

ANYONE KNOWS A BETTER WAY HOW TO BLOCK UNWANTED FAKE CLICKERS
OF GOOGLE ADSENSE??

Anyway here's the script i am using, THE CODE IS WORKING
Furthermore i thow wanna share/upload it again because
The Website Of Author "Szczepan K" is meanwhile DOWN...

```
function requestBlocker()
{
        /*
        Version 1.0 11 Jan 2013
        Author: Szczepan K
        http://www.szczepan.info
        me[@] szczepan [dot] info
        ###Description###
        A PHP function which can Block unwanted Requests to reduce your Website-Traffic.
        God for Spiders, Bots and annoying Clients.
    */

    $dir = 'requestBlocker/'; ## Create & set directory writeable!!!!

    $rules   = array(
            #You can add multiple Rules in a array like this one here
            #Notice that large "sec definitions" (like 60*60*60) will blow up your client File
            array(
                    //if >5 requests in 5 Seconds then Block client 15 Seconds
                    'requests' => 6, 
                    'sek' => 3600, 
                    'blockTime' => 3600 
            ),
            array(
                    //if >10 requests in 30 Seconds then Block client 20 Seconds
                    'requests' => 12, //10 requests
                    'sek' => 600, //10 requests in 30 Seconds
                    'blockTime' => 3600 // Block client 20 Seconds
            ),
          
    );
    $time    = time();
    $blockIt = array();
    $user    = array();
$vpnblock= false;

    #Set Unique Name for each Client-File 
    $user[] = isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : 'IP_unknown';
    $user[] = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : '';
    $user[] = strtolower(gethostbyaddr($user[0]));

    # Notice that i use files because bots does not accept Sessions
    $botFile = $dir . substr($user[0], 0, 8) . '_' . substr(md5(join('', $user)), 0, 5) . '.txt';


    if (file_exists($botFile)) {
            $file   = file_get_contents($botFile);
            $client = unserialize($file);

    } else {
            $client                = array();
            $client['time'][$time] = 0;
    }

    # Set/Unset Blocktime for blocked Clients
    if (isset($client['block'])) {
            foreach ($client['block'] as $ruleNr => $timestampPast) {
                    $left = $time - $timestampPast;
                    if (($left) > $rules[$ruleNr]['blockTime']) {
                            unset($client['block'][$ruleNr]);
                            continue;
                    }
                    $blockIt[] = 'Block active for Rule: ' . $ruleNr . ' - unlock in ' . ($left - $rules[$ruleNr]['blockTime']) . ' Sec.';
            }
            if (!empty($blockIt)) {
                    return $blockIt;
            }



    }

if(isset($client['vpn'])) 
{
    
    $vpnblock = true;
    }
if(!file_exists($botFile))
{
    
    $jsonvpn = file_get_contents("https://vpnapi.io/api/".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."?key=xxxxxxKEY");
            
    if(strlen($jsonvpn) > 124)
    {
        $jsonvpn = json_decode($jsonvpn);

        $xvpn = $jsonvpn->security->vpn;
        $xproxy = $jsonvpn->security->proxy;
        $xtor = $jsonvpn->security->tor;
        $xrelay = $jsonvpn->security->relay;

        if(($xvpn == true )|| ($xproxy == true) || ($xtor == true) || ($xrelay == true ))
        {
            $vpnblock = true;
            
                $client['vpn'][0] = "true";
            

        }
        


    
        
    }
    
    
}



    # log/count each access
    if (!isset($client['time'][$time])) {
            $client['time'][$time] = 1;
    } else {
            $client['time'][$time]++;

    }

    #check the Rules for Client
    $min = array(
            0
    );
    foreach ($rules as $ruleNr => $v) {
            $i            = 0;
            $tr           = false;
            $sum[$ruleNr] = '';
            $requests     = $v['requests'];
            $sek          = $v['sek'];
            foreach ($client['time'] as $timestampPast => $count) {
                    if (($time - $timestampPast) < $sek) {
                            $sum[$ruleNr] += $count;
                            if ($tr == false) {
                                    #register non-use Timestamps for File 
                                    $min[] = $i;
                                    unset($min[0]);
                                    $tr = true;
                            }
                    }
                    $i++;
            }

            if ($sum[$ruleNr] > $requests) {
                    $blockIt[]                = 'Limit : ' . $ruleNr . '=' . $requests . ' requests in ' . $sek . ' seconds!';
                    $client['block'][$ruleNr] = $time;
            }





    }
    $min = min($min) - 1;
    #drop non-use Timestamps in File 
    foreach ($client['time'] as $k => $v) {
            if (!($min <= $i)) {
                    unset($client['time'][$k]);
            }
    }


    $file = file_put_contents($botFile, serialize($client));

if($vpnblock == false)
{
    return $blockIt;
}
else return true;

}


$adprotect = requestBlocker();
```